# Add new page with Div tags

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to add a CMS page from backend to show a form from external link as given below in the code.

But i am unable to display the form on the page as all the div or script tag gets replaced by some ASCII code.

The code that i am trying to add to the CMS Page is

```
<div id="zurmoExternalWebForm"><scripttype="text/javascript"src="http://crm.omegakart.com/app/index.php/contacts/external/sourceFiles?id=1"></script></div>
```

I am using the normal backend process in admin panel to do this.

But the result in front end is same like some text floating on the page.All the code is replaced in between by some ASCII character.

Note: I am re posting this question because someone had put it on hold and even after edit did not bother to unhold the question or reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working in my admin page, I think that code messed up in the way..

Try this code, but disable the editor first

```
<div id="zurmoExternalWebForm"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://crm.omegakart.com/app/index.php/contacts/external/sourceFiles?id=1"></script>
```

Comment: This worked perfect :) Thank you so much.

Comment: glad that worked, could you mark my answer as a solution then :) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the JS by following code.
Use this code in

> admin > cms > pages > edit your page > design tab> custom layout field

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/text" name="your.unique.block. name">
         <action method="setText"> 
              <text> <![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="your js URL"></script>]]> </text>
         </action>
     </block> 
</reference>
```

Another way

You can call any `.phtml` file in the cms page content

```
{{ block type="core/template" name="your.unique.block. name" template="yourfolder/yourfile.phtml"}}
```

Then

```
app/design/frontend/your package/your theme/template/yourfolder/yourfike.phtml
```

In the above path use put the code.
You'll get the output

Comment: Thank you for the help, sorry i couldn't try it as the above answer fixed my issue. But let's keep it might be helping someone else.